# Lit Element - Can I use react query cache in lit element to cache the API response?

Tags: react-query, lit

Here is my case.

I need to surface messages in different pages of a big website. And I plan to use [lit element](https://lit.dev/) to generate a local element <my-element> and used it in different pages. In this element, we need a API call to fetch data from our backend, code like below:

```
    @customElement('my-element')
    export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {

        @property()
        id = 'SomeId';

        render() {
            const response = fetch('https://myendpoint/message?id=' +id);
            return html`<p>Hello, ${response}!</p>`;
        }

    }
```

But in some pages, the message need to be surfaced in each row of table like below

| Id | message |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | `<my-element id=id1 />` |
| id2 | `<my-element id=id2 />` |
| id3 | `<my-element id=id3 />` |

In this way, each lit element will call backend `https://myendpoint/message?id=' +id` to get the message, this is time consuming.

**So assume the backend API `https://myendpoint/message` can fetch all messages belongs to this page in one request, is there any way that we can render above table with only one API call to `https://myendpoint/message`?**

My idea is to leverage ReactQuery cache to cache the API response and filter it by `id`. Then if one API call in  `<my-element id=id1 />`  is completed and the result cached,  other API call in lit element `<my-element id=id2 />`  will directly get response from react cache and there won't be a real network request.

Can somebody here help to confirm if my solution will work? If not, any guidance?

Comment: What does Lit bring to the table? Sounds like you are drawing a table **once** So a native Web Component will be smaller, faster

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Besides the table, the Lit element will be surfaced in many other pages in our website and it will be surfaced only once in most of pages . Then we use Lit Element as the solution and I want to reuse it to render the table. I want to confirm if the ReactQuery Cache can be shared in all the Lit elements in the table and then I can leverage it to reduce the unnecessary API calls.

Comment: React query started as as "react" query, but the react part is now only an adapter to the main tanstack/query library. It also supports vue, svelte, solid, angular and maybe more via other adapters. I doubt you can use the react adapter in Lit, but you can make a new adapter to use the core with Lit. ;)